# Randomly shuffle elements between two lists

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [a, b, c, d, e]

list_2 = [f, g, h, i]
```

What I'm trying to do is a method to shuffe two elements between the list randomly, for example:

```
shuffle_two_lists(list_1, list_2 )

list_1 = [g, b, c, d, e]

list_2 = [f, a, h, i]
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just combine them, `shuffle` and split.

```
import random; random.seed(3.14)

m = len(list_1)
list_3 = list_1 + list_2
random.shuffle(list_3)
list_1, list_2  = list_3[:m], list_3[m:]
```

---

```
print(list_1)
['h', 'a', 'g', 'f', 'b']

print(list_2)
['i', 'e', 'c', 'd']
```